# Build my own light bulb

Tags: short-circuit, light

Before I start: I do not have a lot of experience in electrical engineering so I would appreciate clear statements and extensive explanations to be able to follow your ideas.

I am currently trying to build my own light bulb. The idea is to have a thin Pt wire that I bend such that it shows some letters. The wire shall than be placed in a sealed glas filled with argon and heated by current such that it glows with a red color. The power supply should come from the wall socket (230 V). The problem is, that the wire is much to short because it is not coiled as in conventional light bulbs. Consequently, the resistance is to low and I get a short.

The length of the Pt wire is approx. \$1\$ **m**, the temperature I want to achieve is \$800-1000\$ **°C**, the diameter of the wire is \$1\$ **mm**, the resistivity of Pt is \$\rho = 10.6 \cdot 10^{-8}\$ \$\Omega \cdot\$**m** and the temperature coefficient is \$ \alpha = 0.003927\$ **°C**\$^{-1}\$.

Thus I get a resistance at \$1000\$ **°C** of

\$ R = R_0 \cdot [1+\alpha(T-T_0)]\$ with \$ R_0 = \rho \frac{l}{A}\$; \$A = 7.85 \cdot 10^-7\$ **m**\$^2\$; \$T_0 = 23\$ **°C**

\$ R_0 = 0.134 \$ \$\Omega\$

\$ R(1000°C) = 0.652\$ \$\Omega\$

Do you have a cheap solution how to get the wire glowing without getting a short?

I thought of using a large number of resistors (100-1000) with low resistance  in parallel after the wire. This will decrease the current and the resistors won`t heat to much. What do you think of this idea. Is there a practical way to this?

Comment: Did you estimate the reliability of your device and its MTBF? Use alternative solution - out of the box constant current power supply and set of LEDs.

Comment: I think the reliability should be quite well since I can suppress oxidation and I do not go to extremely high temperatures (I want it glow with 800 °C or so). I dont want to go to LEDs and a constant current power supply is quite expensive and I am not sure which current I need. I will provide all the data that I have in the question.

Comment: The main problem here is that you are approaching this as "I want" Instead go find something existing that is close to your goals and consider if you can change it to meet them.  EL wire might be a possibility.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I am carefully listening to all the answers and I am evaluating whether they would work for me. I know that there are easier ways to do it, but I would like to try it this way because in my opinion it would look the best. I asked the community in the hope that someone might have a cheap and easy solution such that I can stick to my original plan. If it really is impossible, I am still very glad for all the alternative ideas and I will for sure follow them. Nevertheless I think it is not a crime if I prefer to stick to my original plan for now.

Comment: There’s one more thing to calculate: the heat transfer for the wire at 1000C.

Comment: Your design is going to include a transformer one way or another. Looking at filament transformers (from the valve days) will get you started I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want 800degC then maybe you should try coiled nichrome wire. Cheaper, and you can use enough to measure the resistance accurately - it's used in electric fires. You can then work out the current needed to make it glow red hot because you know the mains voltage and (after you unwind it) the length coiled on the heater element. Then it's simply Ohms law or a lab PSU measurement.

Or you can assume it takes approximately mains voltage to drive enough current to make it glow red. So the same current will make any given length glow red.

Typically these are 1kW elements, so if you are in Europe the current is about 4 amps for a 230VAC mains.

Comment: The problem is, that I do not want to use very long wires. I want to have only a couple of letters shining in the glas. And I assume that the nichrome wire in the electric fires is very thin and thus hard to deform. Is there a way to calculate the current required to make it glow red?

Comment: The current to make it glow red, if it is 230VAC rated, is around 4 amps for any length. Only the voltage need change with length. If it is the USA the current is twice that because the voltage is halved for a given power rating. Just get an old electric fire element and try it out. Platinum is not only expensive but 10x more conductive than nichrome

Answer (score 1):

You need to control the current flowing through the wire.

You need to have a power supply that you can limit the current, like a lab power supply where you can adjust the maximum current flowing through the wire.

We would need more details on your setup to provide a better answer.

Comment: You cannot use resistor as then almost no power would be on Pt wire.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem, as well. I added some values in the main question now. I do not know which data I could provide additionally. Thanks for you help!